# Using Cloudwatch log service with older AMIs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to use cloudwatch log service for the programs running on older AMIs (2008-2010). Is there a way I can install it on such machines?.

A workaround which I could think of, is to copy log files from these AMIs to the latest AMI with log service installed and upload the logs from there. But the downside is that I will end up paying cost for data transfer. Is there any alternate better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Henry Hahn gives Amazon Deep Dive CloudWatch presentation and says: ["I am gonna to do a direct install"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=pTzv-i1uvvE#t=1056), you find what you need.

```
$ wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cloudwatch/downloads/latest/awslogs-agent-setup.py
$ sudo python awslogs-agent-setup.py --region eu-west-1
```

(the `--region` can differ in your case)

accepts defaults.

It shall install a service called `awslogs`, which can be started/stopped as any other service.

Configuration file can be found at `/var/awslogs/etc/awslogs.conf`

For me, this worked for my Debian Jessie notebook which is definitely not an EC2 instance, so it shall work for your older EC2 instance as well.

I expect, this will work for RPi instance too (planning to try soon).